# change back icon in toolbar inside Xamarin FormsPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using xamarin forms (PCL), 
I searched a lot but Can not find the exact solution, 
Can i change the back button in toolbar or at least should i be able to change its color and the title color as well?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for changing back button, but I was changing back button and title color.
An example, in App.cs file OnStart method I set that LoginPage is first page with black title, on this way

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage()) { BarTextColor = Color.Black };
```

Please try something like this, I have some other examples if this one doesn't work.

Comment: it changes the title color only but the back button color stay white

Comment: Are you testing just on android platform or on ios also? @Ahmed Sayed

Comment: i test it on android only